# Clang-Format indent class members

Tags: clang, clang-format

Is there a Clang-Format style option to indent class members independantly from access modifiers? In the picture below line 10 is how I'd like it, whereas line 11 is how it's currently formatting.

[image]

```
class AudioService : public IAudioService
{
    public:
        void Prepare(); // how I'd like it

    void Destroy(); // How it currently is formatting

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "independently from access modifiers"? Could you provide the desired result after running `clang-format` on your code?

Comment: I've updated the post with a text version of the code to match the image

Comment: Isn't `Destroy` part of the public accessors in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `AccessModifierOffset` option, which is used to set the extra indent or outdent of access modifiers.

Here is an example `.clang-format`:

```
Language: Cpp
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux
IndentWidth: 8
AccessModifierOffset: -4
```

After calling `clang-format` with this configuration, you'll get the following formatting:

```cpp
class AudioService : public IAudioService
{
    public:
        void Prepare(); // how I'd like it
        void Destroy(); // How it currently is formatting
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it only formats in that way because you have the IndentWidth set to 8, meaning that all other code will be indented too far, inside methods for example